# What is this special character?

Tags: sanskrit

In some youtube sites I can find this word in Sanskrit: `नॉनस्टॉप`, which reads as "nonstop", but when I learned to read Sanskrit, the teacher (I got couple of them) did not mention the second character after "na" with kind of "half-circle" on top.
Where did it come from? Are there some more of these kind of characters?
Thank you!

Comment: It’s pronounced as the o of Greek Omega. It is not a Sanskrit alphabet but used in Devanagari for short O and similarly short E as in elephant. Though nowadays people use E to indicate A for apple but that’s wrong. It’s for E as in Elephant. The letters are ऍ for **E**lephant and ऑ for **O**ffice.